# Corona LUA and OOP Design

Tags: iphone, sdk, lua, coronasdk

So I come from the traditional game development that uses OOP principles and from what I've seen you can mimic this using LUA once you know what you are doing. In some of the code postings I found out how you can use the director class and create files that have a new() function etc.

What I'm looking for is a way to manage my weapons. I have a player and an opponent and I would prefer to have one weapon class, say weaponCanon.  What I have done is:

```
-- private vars here
local power
local canonSprite
local whatever

local someFunction = function()
...
end

-- Private stuff here
local weaponCanon = {}

weaponCanon.fire = function(atX, atY)
...
end

weaponCanon.reset = function()
...
end

return weaponCanon
```

Then in my level code I simply do:

```
local weaponCanon = require("weaponCanon")
weaponCanon.fire(100, 100)
```

This works great and allows me to use a "private" and "public" mentality when coding up my weapons.  The problem is that if I want the player and opponent to have a canon:

```
local playerWeapon = require("weaponCanon")
local opponentWeapon = require("weaponCanon")
```

This simply returns the same object instead of a new instance to that object.  So I only get one weaponCanon at the opponentWeapon location. This is obviously now what I want/need.

Our game has many weapons in it and it would be nice to only have one version of each file with a setting telling us if its the opponents weapon or players weapon.  The alternative is to copy each file and create a weaponPlayerCanon and a weaponOpponentCanon but I cringe at the thought of modifications to one file and having to change 2+ files every time.

How can I make it return an instance and what is the structure of the LUA file to do so?

Thanks or any and all help

-d

Comment: I am well aware of: http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaModuleFunctionCritiqued and this is where I got my design from but its not really solving my problem unless i overlooked something...

Comment: I think what you have missed is you need data and logic. So you need a new function to provide the "table" to contain the settings for your weapon which you would then provide as a parameter for the fire function,  so it decrements the power value for the gun passed table.  Chapter 15 of PIL should set you in the right direction http://www.lua.org/pil/15.html

Comment: What you've done here tells me something I was planning to test out eventually anyway, so thanks for saving me the trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are trying to model a class with your source file. This means you should also have a function to create a new instance of that class unless you want them to share all their state.

Something along the lines of (untested):

```
local WeaponCannon = {}
WeaponCannon.__index = WeaponCannon
function WeaponCannon:new()
  return setmetatable({}, self)
end

function WeaponCannon:fire(x, y)
  -- Do something via the self reference and arguments (x, y)
end

return WeaponCannon
```

And in your calling code (also untested):

```
require('WeaponCannon')
local playerWeapon = WeaponCannon:new()
local opponentWeapon = WeaponCannon:new()
```

Comment: thanks for all the replies I feel all were great solutions.. this one just led me to what I wanted to do.

Comment: Hey, in this example how would you have private variables/functions?  Or does that not exist unless I use a library?

Comment: If they are utility functions that carry no state just put them in the source file and do not return them. Any local variable that you do not expose in the table is also private. As an example `function f() local a = 5; return { getA = function() return a end, setA = function(new_a) a = new_a end } end`. The local variable `a` is only exposed through `getA` and `setA`.

Answer (score 7):

If later on you start needing inheritance (i.e. LaserCannon is a subclass of Weapon) you will probably need to use metatables more profoundly.

There are lots of libraries that will allow you to do "oop on top of Lua". You can see a very good list here:

http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientedProgramming

I'm the author of [middleclass](https://github.com/kikito/middleclass). With my lib, you would have to do something like this:

```
local Weapon = class('Weapon')

function Weapon:initialize(a,b,c)
  self.x,self.y,self.z = a,b,c
end

function Weapon:fire(x,y)
 ...
end
```

LaserCannon would be easy to implement - you just pass a second parameter to class:

```
local LaserCannon = class('LaserCannon', Weapon)

function LaserCannon:initialize(a,b,c,d)
  self.w = d
  Weapon.initialize(self, a,b,c) -- superclass' constructor
end

function LaserCannon:foo()
 ...
end
```

You could use it like this:

```
require 'middleclass' -- so you can use "class"
LaserCannon = require 'laser_cannon'

local playerWeapon = LaserCannon:new() -- a laser
local opponentWeapon = Weapon:new() -- a regular generic weapon

opponentWeapon:fire(100,200) -- typical use
playerWeapon:fire(100, 200) -- LaserCannon inherits fire from Weapon
playerWeapon:foo() -- LaserCannon-exclusive
```

This is with middleclass, which is the one I prefer, since I made it. Other libraries on the page I mentioned before offer similar features.

Comment: I've been looking at your library and do like it a lot.  I may switch over to that soon.  I have been doing some tests but ran into a huge issue.  I'm using it for Corona SDK and ran into a situation when I need to set an onCollision function to be called.  Typically I'd just do:

    self.canonBall.collision = onWeaponCollision
    self.canonBall:addEventListener ("collision", self.canonBall )

However, onWeaponCollision won't work.  Is there a way to still do this with your library?

Read more at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363671/middleclass-problems

Answer (score 1):

Although you create a new table for the weapon object, you don't create new variables. Any variables declared at the top of your module like that are essentially static variables (ie. variables shared by all instances of a class.) To create variables that are unique to that object you need to create them in the table, something like:

```
weaponCannon = {}
weaponCannon.power = 10
```

And anyway you only create an object once, you need a "constructor" function that creates the tables:

```
function new()
  local weaponCannon = {}
  weaponCannon.power = 10
end
```

---

---

Incidentally, two other things that aren't directly related to your answer but can be very useful modifications to your code. First off, using a colon instead of a period to call functions in a method will allow you to use the "self" keyword inside the method, something like:

```
function weaponCannon:fire()
  --this is only a test
  print(self.power)
end
```

then

```
local playerWeapon = require("weaponCanon")
playerWeapon:fire()
```

Second, you can actually use display objects as tables, rather than having to create an empty table and then sticking the display object into that empty table:

```
weaponCannon = display.newImage("cannon.png")
weaponCannon.power = 10
```

Note that you can't set the meta-table if you do this however. I find this approach looks more logical and prefer not to use meta-tables myself, but that's your call.

Answer (score 0):

There are no objects here- you just have a bunch of global data. You really need to be making instances.

```
function NewWeapon(arg)
    return {
        fire = function(self, atX, atY) 
            print(self.var)
        end,
        var = arg,
    }
end

NewWeapon(3):fire(1, 2)
NewWeapon(7):fire(3, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like ponzao's answer. Would however change it to:

```
local WeaponCannon = {}

function WeaponCannon:new()
  local instance = {}
  setmetatable(instance, {__index = WeaponCannon})
  -- setup your new instance here
  return instance
end

function WeaponCannon:fire(x, y)
  -- Do something via the self reference and arguments (x, y)
end

return WeaponCannon
```

And in your calling code:

```
local WeaponCanon = require('WeaponCannon')
local playerWeapon = WeaponCannon:new()
local opponentWeapon = WeaponCannon:new()
```

What I've changed:

- Created a local instance variable to allow for setup before returning it
- More compact way of setting the metatable
- Use a variable for the class when calling the code